# How do I figure out why Node is taking a long time to start?

Tags: node.js

I'm using `forever` to restart my Node server whenever I change a file. However, it takes 5-10 seconds even though I don't have much code yet. I think there may a configuration problem or an unnecessary slow module. How would I figure out what Node is doing during those 5-10 seconds?

Comment: Only forever takes this time or when you run from node?

Comment: It's roughly the same time when I run directly. However, I'm using Browser Sync, so it's really obvious when `forever` restarts it (I have isomorphic code that triggers a client-side and server-side refresh).

Comment: listing out modules could help or posting a sample code which you think maybe causing the problem could help understand your problem.

Comment: If I just list out the modules and someone tells me about a glitch in one of those modules, then I have to ask again the next time there's a bottleneck. I'm looking for a generic way to debug Node startup.